# Call a Python script using a batch file

Tags: python, csv, batch-file, command-line

Hi im trying to run a jupyter notebook script through a batch file.

It creates a dataframe and exports it to a csv. I've downloaded the jupyter notebook script as a .py and then used the following line of code in a batch file to try run it:

```
c:\python27\python.exe H:\python\development\notebooks\jackson\test.py %*
```

but the folder where the csv exports to isn't updated when i run the batch file. 
when i click it there is a pop up for a very short time and then appears to do nothing.

All help appreciated

Comment: open a cmd, navigate to the folder where the python file is and just type its name. You do not need `python.exe` in front of it or `%*` at the back

Comment: If you run the batchfile from command line you can read the output and possible error messages. Or you could add the line `pause` at the end of the batchfile. This prevents the window from closing.